# Ошибка при использовании list_display в django

Tags: python, django, listview, django-admin

Моя задача получить табличный вид таблиц базы данных в админке Джанго. У меня есть импортированная из Mysql таблица в файле models.py

```
class Stations2(models.Model):
    id_stations = models.IntegerField(db_column='ID_stations', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    name = models.TextField(db_column='Name', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    type = models.TextField(db_column='Type', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    country = models.TextField(db_column='Country', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    latitude = models.FloatField(db_column='Latitude', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    longitude = models.FloatField(db_column='Longitude', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    elevation = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    site_gaw_id = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    stations_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'stations_2'
```

А также есть в файле  admin.py попытка использования этой таблицы:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Stations2


class data_admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Stations2
    list_display = ('Name', 'Type',)

admin.site.register(Stations2,data_admin)
```

Правда,не совсем удачная

```
ERRORS:
<class 'scrapping_2.admin.data_admin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[0]' refers to 'Name', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'data_admin', or an attribute or method on 'scrapping_2.Stations2'.
<class 'scrapping_2.admin.data_admin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[1]' refers to 'Type', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'data_admin', or an attribute or method on 'scrapping_2.Stations2'.
```

Если убрать `data_admin` из `admin.site.register`, то сайт запускается. Вопрос: как решить данну

Answer (score 1):

1. Ваша ошибка в названии полей в list_display. Необходимо исправить на `list_display = ('name', 'type',)`. По сколько в models.py они называются именно так.
2. Название классов в Python(Django) принято называть по принципу CamelCase, `class DataAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):`
3. Ошибка в `type = models.TextField()`, type - это зарезервированное слово, его не желательно использовать для названия переменных.
   Хорошего дня !